# Debian 10 Service not starting

Tags: debian, systemd, services, systemctl

Hello everyone,

I want to create a service for Debian 10, but when I try to run it with the command “*sudo systemctl start boot_time*”, it doesn’t start. But it does start if I launch the script itself.

I have set the chmod rights on both files.

Boot_time.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash 

AppLauncher
```

Boot_time.service :

```
[Unit] 

Description=Launch AppLauncher when distro is booting 



[Service] 

Type=simple 

ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/boot_time.sh 

Restart=on-failure 



[Install] 

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here are the logs when I run “*sudo systemctl start boot_time.service*” :

```
● boot_time.service - Launch AppLauncher when distro is booting 
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/boot_time.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-12-10 22:56:35 CET; 13s ago 
Process: 1513 ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/boot_time.sh (code=exited, status=134) 
Main PID: 1513 (code=exited, status=134)déc. 10 22:56:35 debian bash[1513]: /usr/bin/boot_time.sh : ligne 3 : 1514 Abandon AppLauncher 
déc. 10 22:56:35 debian systemd[1]: boot_time.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=134/n/a 
déc. 10 22:56:35 debian systemd[1]: boot_time.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 
déc. 10 22:56:35 debian systemd[1]: boot_time.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart. 
déc. 10 22:56:35 debian systemd[1]: boot_time.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5. 
déc. 10 22:56:35 debian systemd[1]: Stopped Launch AppLauncher when distro is booting. 
déc. 10 22:56:35 debian systemd[1]: boot_time.service: Start request repeated too quickly. 
déc. 10 22:56:35 debian systemd[1]: boot_time.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 
déc. 10 22:56:35 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start Launch AppLauncher when distro is booting.
```

Do you have any ideas regarding this problem I’m facing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you run `sudo journalctl -u boot_time.service -b` after the failure, you should get a more verbose and usually a very descriptive log entry with regards to the error. Also, does your script only execute that one command `AppLauncher` ? And if so, what does that one command do exactly? Is it meant to somehow hook to a user's session, which could be problematic if a user session has not been initialized yet. Finally, the `/usr/bin/boot_time.sh : ligne 3 : 1514 Abandon AppLauncher` line implies something about line 3 in boot_time.sh. but the `Abandon` directive is not native to systemd log.

Comment: If AppLauncher is a GUI program, your `boot_time.service` has no After dependencies and so systemd will attempt to start it as soon as it can - even before the GUI subsystem has been started. And if the GUI subsystem is not running, any GUI application will simply fail unless it has an alternative non-GUI mode built in. It would be better to tie GUI program start-up to the startup of the GUI subsystem or desktop environment, depending on when exactly you want the program to start: after GUI login, before it, or *instead of* it (i.e. for kiosk-type solutions)?

Comment: The question does not give enough detail what you exactly want to do. But speculating that you want to launch a GUI, consider doing it in a user service manager (`systemctl --user`) instead of in the system service manager. But even there you need to make sure that you have dependencies and environment variables available.